# How to validate Youtube Url validateOnly Laravel Livewire

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-7, laravel-livewire

I'm trying to validate that a youtube address is put in the youtube url, I don't want it to be something strict but at least it can be verified that it doesn't put anything. I am trying to customize the validations and I do not discover how they are done, can you please help me.

I would like to implement something like this:

```
$rx = '~
  ^(?:https?://)?                           # Optional protocol
   (?:www[.])?                              # Optional sub-domain
   (?:youtube[.]com/watch[?]v=|youtu[.]be/) # Mandatory domain name (w/ query string in .com)
   ([^&]{11})                               # Video id of 11 characters as capture group 1
    ~x';

$has_match = preg_match($rx, $url, $matches);
```

I use real-time validation as follows:

```
public function updated($field)

    {

        $this->validateOnly($field, [

            'name' => 'required|max:255|min:3',

            'last_name' => 'required|max:255|min:3',

            'password' => 'min:6|required',

            'password_confirmation' => 'same:password',

            'email' => 'unique:App\User,email|required|email',

        ]);

    }
```

Can you add a custom validation? I would greatly appreciate an example of how it can be done. Thank you for spending time in my consultation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add custom rule:

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return (bool) preg_match('/^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=|\?v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/',$value);
    }
```

**Validate:**

```
'video' => new RuleYoutube,
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a `regex` validation rule for this:

```php
$rx = '~
  ^(?:https?://)?                           # Optional protocol
   (?:www[.])?                              # Optional sub-domain
   (?:youtube[.]com/watch[?]v=|youtu[.]be/) # Mandatory domain name (w/ query string in .com)
   ([^&]{11})                               # Video id of 11 characters as capture group 1
    ~x';

$this->validateOnly($field, [
    'youtube_url' => "regex:$rx",
]);
```

Comment: I am trying to add the function in the component but the $ rx variable gives me an error. Could you please tell me if this is added like this or should I create another function? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer may accept not valid Youtube links, for example this link `https://www.xxx.be/watch?v=wxQuTsgMw3Y` will pass validation!

You can use this:

```
        'input_name' => [
            'required',
            'url',
            function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                if (!preg_match('/(youtube.com|youtu.be)\/(watch)?(\?v=)?(\S+)?/', $value)) {
                    $fail(trans("general.not_youtube_url", ["name" => trans("general.url")]));
                }
            },
        ],
```